# A word that means "to start talking about things that are out of topic."

Tags: word-request

Here are a few definitions for the word:
To steer away from the main topic.
To take a walk on a path of topic way off from the intended one.

Answer (score 7):

I remembered the word while typing the question.

> digress

http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/digress

Comment: A couple of synonmous idiomatic expressions include: _go off on a tangent_ and _get sidetracked_.

Comment: "Digress" is perfect. Other D words: "Diverge" implies that the "Detour" is "unDirected."

Answer (score 0):

Some good synonyms are Trail Off and Ramble. – lurker Dec 27 '15 at 21:09

Sometimes [*trail off*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/trail+off) can refer to volume, where the speaker doesn't change the subject, but just starts mumbling. – J.R.♦ Dec 27 '15 at 21:31

This may not be exactly what you were looking for, but an idiom for a long, rambling story, with many digressions, that does not really go where the listener was expecting is a shaggy dog story. – stangdon Dec 27 '15 at 23:21

Answer (score 0):

Troll.

But this usually refers to someone who deliberately joins a discussion because he/she wants to kill the topic.

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary). See the Help Center article [answer].